# Javascript - Create new object after searching through a different array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, mongoose

I have an array of dates as follows...

```
dateArray : 2018-12-15,2018-11-20,2018-12-20
```

And I have an array of objects as follows...

```
{ _id: 5bf454d9c4a8bc6e246afd05,
 date: '2018-12-15',
 time: '9:00 - 10:00',
 status: 'available',
 price: 35 },
{ _id: 5bf455adf678f76f7ffb9144,
 date: '2018-11-20',
 time: '15:00 - 16:00',
 status: 'available',
 price: 55 },
{ _id: 5bf455caf678f76f7ffb914b,
 date: '2018-11-20',
 time: '12:00 - 13:00',
 status: 'available',
 price: 45 },
{ _id: 5bfec692d25d720f29eb49e1,
  date: '2018-12-20',
  time: '9:00 - 10:00',
  status: 'available',
  price: 33 }
```

What I'm trying to do is take each date value in dateArray, search for this date in the array of objects, and return a new object with a structure something like this...

```
{
"date": "2018-12-15",
"timePrice": [
    {
        "time": "9:00 - 10:00",
        "price": 35
    }
    ],
}{
"date": "2018-11-20",
"timePrice": [
    {
        "time": "12:00 - 13:00",
        "price": 45
    },
    {
        "time": "15:00 - 16:00",
        "price": 55
    },

   ]
}
```

Basically I'd like to group by one unique date and then have nested objects inside each date which contain the times for that date. Any ideas how I could go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `reduce()` over the dates and then for each date, `filter()` the items you want to build a new object:

```js
const dateArray =  ['2018-12-15', '2018-11-20', '2018-12-20']
const prices = [{ _id: '5bf454d9c4a8bc6e246afd05',date: '2018-12-15',time: '9:00 - 10:00',status: 'available',price: 35 },{ _id: '5bf455adf678f76f7ffb9144',date: '2018-11-20',time: '15:00 - 16:00',status: 'available',price: 55 },{ _id: '5bf455caf678f76f7ffb914b',date: '2018-11-20',time: '12:00 - 13:00',status: 'available',price: 45 },{ _id: '5bfec692d25d720f29eb49e1',date: '2018-12-20',time: '9:00 - 10:00',status: 'available',price: 33 }]

let obj = dateArray.reduce((obj, date) => {
    if (!obj[date]) obj[date] = {date, timePrice:[]}

    // get prices for specific date
    let pr = prices.filter(item => item.date === date)

    // for each price push just the time and price values as a new object
    obj[date].timePrice.push(pr.map(({time, price}) => ({time, price})))
    return obj
}, {} )

// Object.values(obj) will be your array
console.log(Object.values(obj))
```

Comment: This works perfectly for what I need. Thanks so much!